# Evaluate a simple string mathematical expression

Tags: c++

I've just taken a test for a graduate C++ developer with the question below.  It didn't go too well as I couldn't decide on a clear way of completing the task.  Time limit didn't help either.  I'm interested in how experienced developers would have tackled the follow problem - in pseudo or sample code:

```
Evaluate

Write a function in C or C++ that evaluates the result of a simple expression.
The function should ignore whitespace, but stop at the first non valid character.
Valid tokens are listed in the table below:

0-9 - Only integers are allowed in expressions

() - Nested expressions should be evaluated first.

+, -, *, / - Basic operators are addition, subtraction, multiplication and division.

The expression should be parsed from left to right. It is not necessary to consider operator precedence in your solution (e.g. 1 + 3 * 4 = 16). If there is an error in the expression, the function should return false.

Suggested prototype for function:

Example:

bool evaluate(const char *expression, int &result)
{
...
}

**Input**
1+3
(1 + (12 * 2)

**Result**
4
N/A

**Return code**
true
false (missing bracket)
```

In addition, this is the 2nd C++ that I've failed to complete successfully.  Have had 1 year intership experiece and 1 year academic experiece using C++, but I'm not prepared for some of these tests.  Are there any recommended resources where I can attept to solve problems such as this one in order to gain more 'testing' experience?

Comment: Do you know about _grammars_, say for instance the _BNF grammar_ for a math expression?

Comment: Look for a College-level *Introduction* To Compilers Course (and related books/course material). One of the first assignments should be to construct a simple lexer/parse/rec-decent (or similar) to parse "Math Equations". A simple grammar like this can actually be "punted" with just using a stack and processing as it is read in because of "it is not necessary to consider precedence". In any case, "not a real question".

Comment: @K-ballo: BNF grammar is overkill and will probably give you the wrong answer as the question above assumes no precedence while if you pull a grammar of the web it will use precedence.

Comment: @Loki Astari: I see parens for nested expressions in the OP code. But I see your point on operator precedence, right.

Comment: @K-ballo: I see `It is not necessary to consider operator precedence in your solution`. Which means a BNF grammar id overkill. You just need a stack to push items as you parse them. See my answer below.

Comment: I can not see how this question fits any of these categories to qualify for a close. This is obviously an over-aggressive close. 1: You can tell what is being asked for (1 help with code or pseudo/ 2 recommended resources). 2: It is not `ambiguous, vague, incomplete` as there is a very detailed specific question. It is not rhetorical and can be answered in the current forum as shown by three good answers.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is mostly parsing, which would be covered in a compiler course probably in second or third year. Once you can parse expressions to build up a recursive data structure representing the input (called a syntax tree) it's pretty trivial to evaluate such expressions. A recursive decent parser can also evaluate the expression as it goes without actually building a syntax tree.

For a full treatment you'd want a book on compilers, such as the dragon book. Also IIRC the book *Programming: Principals and Practice using C++* covers an example like this.

You could also wait for chapter ten of *The Art of Computer Programming* to be published, which will cover parsing. It's scheduled to be out around 2020.

Comment: Is that _TAOCP_ reference a joke, or is it really scheduled 2020??

Comment: Knuth says it right on his page: Volume 5 ["Estimated to be ready in 2020."](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/taocp.html) The joke I'd first planned was "Should be ready any day now." Knuth started writing his book on compilers in 1962, so...

Answer (score 1):

Here is my shortest attempt. It took about 40 minutes to type up, you can play with it on ideone ([link](http://ideone.com/fvV8C)).

The code is very straightforward, assuming that you have at least a cursory familiarity with the basic [*recursive descent parsing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) technique.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;
bool eval_expr(const char **pe, int &lhs, bool inside = false);
// gets the next char after skipping optional whitespace
char skip_ws(const char **pe) {
    while (**pe == ' ') ++(*pe);
    return **pe;
}
// evaluates a parenthesized expression or a number
bool eval_prim(const char **pe, int &res) {
    char c = skip_ws(pe);
    if (c == '(') {
        ++(*pe);
        if (!eval_expr(pe, res, true)) return false;
        ++(*pe);
        return true;
    }
    if (isdigit(c)) {
        res = 0;
        while (isdigit(c)) {
            res = 10*res + c - '0';
            c = *(++(*pe));
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
// evaluates a chain of + - * / operations
bool eval_expr(const char **pe, int &lhs, bool inside) {
    if (!eval_prim(pe, lhs)) return false;
    char op;
    while ((op = skip_ws(pe)) && (op == '+' || op == '-' || op == '*' || op == '/')) {
        ++(*pe);
        int rhs;
        if (!eval_prim(pe, rhs)) return false;
        switch (op) {
            case '+': lhs += rhs; break;
            case '-': lhs -= rhs; break;
            case '*': lhs *= rhs; break;
            case '/': lhs /= rhs; break;
        }
    }
    return inside ? op == ')' : !op;
}
// wrapper API to hide an extra level of indirection
bool evaluate(const char *e, int &result) {
    return eval_expr(&e, result);
}
```

Comment: According to this, 9-4*6 = 30

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk That's absolutely right, the code does not pay attention to operator precedence. I did this on purpose, to avoid cluttering the code with secondary things. Anyone familiar with recursive descent parsing should be able to figure out how to improve this code to deal with precedence, additional operators, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple scan push apply (the twist is the braces).

1. Look for a number:

   - If you see a number push onto stack
   - if you see a '(' push it onto stack and **goto 1**
   - Otherwise an error.
2. Look for an op:

   - If you see an op push it onto stack
   - Otherwise an error
3. Look for a number:

   - If you see a number push onto stack
   - If you see a '(' push onto stack and **goto 1**
   - Otherwise an error
4. pop last three items from the stack  (should be number op number)

   - do the operation and push the result onto the stack.
5. Now the complex bit:

   - Peek to see if the next character is a **')'** if it is goto "PopCode" below.
6. If no more input **goto 7**.

   - Otherewise **goto 2**
7. If only one item on the stack you have your result.

   - Otherwise an error.

PopCode

1. Pop last two values from the stack. Should be '( Number'

   - If it is not then an error
2. Throw away the '('
3. If the top of the stack is an op push value **goto 4 (above)**
4. Otherwise push the value onto the stack **goto 5 (above)**

When finished there should be one number on the stack.

Example:

```
1+3
Rule 1: push 1             stack = '1'
Rule 2: push +             stack = '1 +'
Rule 3: push 3             stack = '1 + 3'
Rule 4: pop and do:        stack = '4'
Rule 5: Nothing            stack = '4'
Rule 6: goto 7             stack = '4'
Rule 7:                    stack = '4'

(1 + (12 * 2)
Rule 1: push ( goto 1      stack = '('
Rule 1: push 1             stack = '( 1'
Rule 2: push +             stack = '( 1 +'
Rule 3: push ( goto 1      stack = '( 1 + ('
Rule 1: push 12            stack = '( 1 + ( 12'
Rule 2: push *             stack = '( 1 + ( 12 *'
Rule 3: push 2             stack = '( 1 + ( 12 * 2'
Rule 4: Pop and do:        stack = '( 1 + ( 24'
Rule 5: Do 'PopCode'       stack = '( 1 + ( 24'
Pop  1: Pop 2              stack = '( 1 +'
Pop  2: Holding 24         stack = '( 1 +'
Pop  3: push 24 goto 4     stack = '( 1 + 24'
Rule 4: Pop and do         stack = '( 25'
Rule 5: Nothing            stack = '( 25'
Rule 6: goto 7             stacj = '( 25'
Rule 7: More than 1 item error

Re-Doing with correct formula
(1 + (12 * 2))
Rule 1: push ( goto 1      stack = '('
Rule 1: push 1             stack = '( 1'
Rule 2: push +             stack = '( 1 +'
Rule 3: push ( goto 1      stack = '( 1 + ('
Rule 1: push 12            stack = '( 1 + ( 12'
Rule 2: push *             stack = '( 1 + ( 12 *'
Rule 3: push 2             stack = '( 1 + ( 12 * 2'
Rule 4: Pop and do:        stack = '( 1 + ( 24'
Rule 5: Do 'PopCode'       stack = '( 1 + ( 24'
Pop  1: Pop 2              stack = '( 1 +'
Pop  2: Holding 24         stack = '( 1 +'
Pop  3: push 24 goto 4     stack = '( 1 + 24'
Rule 4: Pop and do         stack = '( 25'
Rule 5: Do 'PopCode'       stack = '( 25'
Pop  1: Pop 2              stack = ''
Pop  2: holding 25         stack = ''
Pop  3: Nothing.           stack = ''
Pop  4: push 25 goto 5     stack = '25'
Rule 5: Nothing            stack = '25'
Rule 6: goto 7             stack = '25'
Rule 7: Result = 25
```

Answer (score 1):

Begin with a simple grammar:

```
expr: n-expr {o-expr} | p-expr {o-expr}
n-expr: [0-9]n-expr
p-expr: ( expr )
o-expr: op expr
op: + | - | * | /
```

This is probably the largest hurdle for the question. You want to be able to write a simple top down recursive descent parser, so your grammar needs to be written in a way to allow that to happen.

Then, the implementation from there is fairly straightforward:

```
bool expr (const char *&s, int &result, int eos = 0) {
    while (isspace(*s)) ++s;
    if (*s == eos) return false;
    if (isdigit(*s)) {
        if (!n_expr(s, result)) return false;
    } else if (*s == '(') {
        if (!p_expr(s, result)) return false;
    } else return false;
    while (isspace(*s)) ++s;
    if (*s == eos) return true;
    return o_expr(s, result, eos);
}

bool n_expr (const char *&s, int &result) {
    int n = 0;
    while (isdigit(*s)) n = 10 * n + (*s++ - '0');
    result = n;
    return true;
}

bool p_expr (const char *&s, int &result) {
    if (expr(++s, result, ')')) {
        ++s;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool o_expr (const char *&s, int &result, int eos) {
    int oresult = 0;
    const char *op = strchr("+-*/", *s);
    if (op == 0) return false;
    if (!expr(++s, oresult, eos)) return false;
    switch (*op) {
    case '+': result += oresult; break;
    case '-': result -= oresult; break;
    case '*': result *= oresult; break;
    case '/': result /= oresult; break;
    default: return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: According to this, 2/2/10 = 10

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk: No, that would result in core dump, since 2/10 is 0, and 2/0 is a floating point exception. The code implements the grammar, and the grammar specifies a right to left computation of the expression. The point of the example is to illustrate how to implement a grammar.

Comment: I actually ran this and that's the result I got.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk: [You ran it wrong](http://ideone.com/1D2IUk).

Comment: ahh, that explains it, I changed int to float http://ideone.com/xg7oPT

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk: Again, that is right to left computation.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve a (not necessarily) simple mathematical expression is to use the [Shunting Yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) to convert it to [Reverse Polish Notation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReversePolishNotation.html), which is almost trivial to parse using a stack. Of course it might not be feasible to do so for an assignment or an interview (perhaps unless a SY algorithm reference is available).