# Arduino | String to Int Math Expression

Tags: arduino

I have string math expression. I want to convert this expression to integer.

Example:

```
    char str[]="2*5";
```

So, I need to get 10 for this example in arduino. How can I do that ?

Comment: This is very close to your question and should help you to find the solution of refine the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329406/evaluating-arithmetic-expressions-from-string-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a naive solution would be to split the expression (using regex or even sscanf [even though i do not recommend it] ) to numbers (cast the numbers to int\doubles of course) and operator(that could stay as a string )
and switch case the math operator action with the numbers (as in activating the relevant operator).

a better solution in my opinion is to use [SY algorithem (wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) to convert 
the expression to a [Reverse Polish notation(wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) which makes things much easier to parse and work with (especially if youll use a stack to parse it )

also found some useful answers [here(evaluating from string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329406/evaluating-arithmetic-expressions-from-string-in-c), [here (split string with math expression)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013134/split-string-with-math-expression) and my personal favorite [here (evaluate arithmetic from string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172217/evaluate-a-simple-string-mathmatical-expression)

Answer (score 1):

I did it with TinyExpr library. It worked like a charm !

https://github.com/codeplea/tinyexpr/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Excellent advice, and excellent library. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this in quotation marks. Maybe you want just parse it to String:

```
int x = 2*5
String myString = String(x);
```

Comment: But I'm getting expression in string type. So I need parse string to int.

Comment: Then, use  ' toInt() '  function on string object, but you can't do math in string.

Comment: "2*5" returns 2.